# scapy Deauthentication address understanding

Tags: network, wifi, network-scanners

I have the problem to understand from_DS, to_DS with Deauthentication packet,

> deauthentication packets are type=Managment,
>   FCfield managment and control frames always FROM_DS = 0 , TO_DS=0,
>   rules for address fileds: addr1 is used for the receiver, addr2 for transmitter, addr3 used for filtering by receiver

but Deauthenticating packet can be sent from AccessPoint --> Station,
and from Station ---> AccessPoint,

```
AccessPoint --> Station      
addr1= station(RA=DA) also this addres can be BROADCAST ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
addr2= mac_ap (TA=SA) 
addr3= (BSSID)


Station--> AccessPoint 
addr1= mac_ap(RA=DA)
addr2= station(TA=SA)
addr3= mac_ap (BSSID)
```

how correct resolve all address from who to who send this packet, only with compare

```
if addr3 == addr2 this packet send from access point,
or something similar?
```

Do I have some fundamental misunderstanding of what's happening here?